# How to check if '@' is present in a string

Tags: delphi

I tried using an If statement , but it only shows the message if i only put @ in the edit

```
var
sname , email : string ;
iAge , igrade : integer ;
iVal : string;

begin
ival := '@';
email :=  (edtEmail.Text);
if ival = email then


 begin


Showmessage(' Email Address must contain @ ');
 end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the condition `ival = email` is `true` [iff](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iff) `ival` and `email` are identical strings. Since `ival` is `@`, the condition is true iff `email` is exactly `@`.

You want to check if `@` is found inside `email`. To do this, you can use the [`Pos`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos) function, which returns the 1-based index of the first character of the first occurrence of a substring within a string, or `0` is the substring isn't found in the string:

```
if Pos('@', email) = 0 then
  ShowMessage('The email address must contain @.');
```

Notice that there really isn't any need for a variable to hold the at character.

In modern versions of Delphi, it is better to write

```
if not email.Contains('@') then
  ShowMessage('The email address must contain @.');
```

using [`TStringHelper.Contains`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Contains), since this is easier to read.

Comment: thanks a lot Andreas !

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pos function to check if the @ character can be located in the email string.

```
if Pos('@', email) = 0 then
begin
   Showmessage(' Email Address must contain @ ');
end;
```

Here is an article about validating email addresses in Delphi

https://www.howtodothings.com/computers/a1169-validating-email-addresses-in-delphi.html

Comment: Thanks so much Charlie !